# How to walk through nodes in XSL for-each?

Tags: xslt

How to visualize the following XML

```
<Root>
 <name1> 
  <node1>  some text  </node1> 
  <node2>  <node22/>  <node23/>  </node2>  
 </name1> 
 <name2>   
  <node1>  some text  </node1> 
  <node2>  <node22/>  <node23/>  </node2>  
 </name2>   
</Root>
```

The name of these *node1, node12, node13, Root* nodes are known, but *name1, name2,* etc. are unknown in advance.

The desired output should be a set of two tables for each *name*, one for *node1* and other for *node2*.

My problem is that I can't iterate over *nameX* because I don't know the exact name of the node. In the example above I used *nameX* but it can be any valid name.

Comment: Could you add the expected output of your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The desired output should be a set of two tables for each name, one
>   for node1 and other for node2.

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <table>
                <!-- build your table here -->
            </table>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: How to get the name that comes from the Astrix ? I need it to create the name of the table .

Comment: Use either the `name()` or the  `local-name()` function to get the name of the current node. -- You really should post a complete question, if you want a complete answer.